# Convert pdf URL to Base64

Tags: angular, pdf, base64

In my angular application, I used the below code for convert any **file** to **Base64** string.

```
handleUpload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
        console.log(reader.result);
    };
}
```

Here, I want to convert the **pdf URL** to **base64** on the fly. Here's my sample URL which I want to convert base64.

https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` to get the file from url. First you have to import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
imports: [...,
     'HttpClientModule',
       ...]
```

After that import in your component.ts `HttpClient` from `'@angular/common/http'` and add the instance in the constructor.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

add the method

```
convertToBase64(url: string) {
    this.http.get(url, { responseType: "blob" }).subscribe(blob => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const binaryString = reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        //Here you can do whatever you want with the base64 String
        console.log("File in Base64: ", event.target.result);
      };

      reader.onerror = (event: any) => {
        console.log("File could not be read: " + event.target.error.code);
      };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getBase64(file) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
         reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
}

var file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0];
getBase64(file).then(
   data => console.log(data)
);
```